# Issue with accessing profile

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

Yesterday I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598928/java-generics-in-arraylist-toarray) because of which I earned 200+ points (daily max limit) in a day. But after some time I was not able to open my profile neither was I able to post any question. While I could view other users' profile without any glitch.

Was that just some strange issue with SO or is there some policy because of which my profile was inaccessible for some time? Weird part was that the profile of the person, who asked the question, was also inaccessible.

Below was the redirect URL that was being requested from the browser when I tried to acccess my profile:

http://182.79.218.37:8080/webadmin/deny/index.php?dpid=1&dpruleid=3&cat=107&ttl=0&groupname=-&policyname=-&username=-&userip=162.158.46.146&connectionip=127.0.0.1&nsphostname=Policy07-Mumbai&protocol=policyprocessor&dplanguage=-&url=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow%2ecom%2fusers%2f4274119%2fsudhir%2dsingh

And below is screenshot from Chrome's DevTool:

[image]

Comment: Looks like an issue with either your proxy or firewall, or you have a virus.

Comment: But I never faced that problem earlier and at the same time I was able to access other user's profile, except the profile of the user who asked that question.

Comment: Test if you can browse to it over https.

Comment: I tried but it did not work yesterday. Now I don't have any problem event with http.

Answer (score 2):

Following that url you posted gives me this message:

> “Your requested URL has been blocked as per the directions received from Department of Telecommunications, Government of India. Please contact administrator for more information.”

which is a similar request to one on [MSE about superuser.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278276/why-is-superuser-com-blocked) being blocked. <sup>[<10K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEtPx.png)</sup>

It looks like your local government/authorities have reasons to believe that the servers in the StackExchange network are harmful for their citizens, hence their action to block those sites.

If you feel this is done in error raise a complaint at your local government/authority representative. Stack Overflow, Inc. can't help you with that.

There are ways to circumvent the blocking either by using a VPN to connect to a server outside your country or using [Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/).